# Read video with transparent background into matlab

Tags: matlab, video, video-processing

I'm looking for a way to load video with transparency mask into Matlab (example: Quicktime MOV PNG Format with a transparent background). I need to get the image and transparency mask for every frame I read.

This is the way to do it with images: [A,map,transparency] = imread(___). 
What is the way to do it with video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

transparency is handled by the *alpha channel* in RGBA and by a bit in TGA / TARGA ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Other_transparency_methods )

RGBA is 32 bit and so a *(m x n x 4 )-matrix*, where *m,n* are *width* and *height* of the image frame

so any tools like `video = readFrame(v,'native')` can not be used because they return a *(m x n x 3)-matrix* ( RGB24 )

`.png` and `.tiff`-based videos support alpha channel ( https://www.digitalrebellion.com/blog/posts/list_of_video_formats_supporting_alpha_channels )

so possibly the easiest solution use `CreateMovie` from the *Psychtoolbox*  ( `mex`-based ) that is able to create movies from RGBA 32-bit images :

> 'numChannels' Optional number of image channels to encode: Can be 1, 3
>   or 4 on OpenGL graphics hardware, and 3 or 4 on OpenGL-ES hardware. 1
>   = Red/Grayscale channel only, 3 = RGB, **4 = RGBA**. Please note that not all video codecs can encode pure 1 channel data or RGBA data, ie. an
>   alpha channel.

source : http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/CreateMovie

there are functions for RGBA image processing in matlab however they can not be used in combination with the standard video functions in matlab because they do not support RGBA videos ( `.avi`, `.jpeg`,... is without alpha channel ), cf https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.readrgbaimage.html